# Android API levels and APK files

Tags: android, apk

I am new to Android, and working with a beginner-level test application.

My question is, for different API levels for different device, i must create several .apk files or i can combine them in one? I am confused.

Any help will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: No, you just need one apk. You're overthinking this. Just create an application and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Android documentation on API levels:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, in your build.gradle file (the inner build.gradle file, not the outer one) you define your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. This essentially is your "bounds" for the device API's that are supported by your project. You therefore are "combining", so to speak, all the various android API's that can run your app. Ex:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

If you aren't using Android Studio, you define the sdk versions in the AndroidManifest.xml file via . EX:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
```

Note that build.gradle will override whatever you do in the AndroidManifest.xml

So, to answer you question, you compile one version of an apk for your app, with a bounds for which sdks are supported in your application. For different devices (tablets, phablets, etc..) you create different resource folders to target those devices. Different APKs are sometimes though compiled separately for targeting tablets vs. phones to minimize the size of the APK.